# Find $E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]$ if $X$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, expected-value

> Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with parameter $p$. Find the expectation of $\frac{1}{1+X}$.

I understand that $\sum\frac{1}{1+x}p(x)...$ then $\sum\frac{1}{1+x}p(1-p)^{x-1}$. I need help simplifying the series.

Comment: There are [two definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) of this distribution. Are you saying $P(X=k)=p(1-p)^k$ for $k\ge0$, or $P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for $k\ge1$?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can solve your exercise using (and understanding)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}=\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right).$$